Is there a way to query GCP Dataplex tag values that are attached to BigQuery tables?
BigQuery tables can have metadata attached via tags, and I'd like to query that tag information to check how many tables in a given project or schema are missing certain tag values. I don't see tag metadata available in information_schema. Is there a way to query tag data?

Hi @strato,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer.

You can view tags attached to a table by using the console,bq command and API.
Console:
Step1: In the Google Cloud console, go to the BigQuery page.
Step2: In the Explorer pane, expand your project and dataset, and then select a table. The tags are visible in the Details tab.
Bq command:
bq show PROJECT_ID:DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID

According to this google cloud documentation,it seems like we  cannot find the tag information directly by running a query. To view the tags associated with the table you can use any of the above mentioned methods.
For more information refer to these link1,link2 and link3.
